# Pass var and refresh Div on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following code, the alert works fine. the div refreshes fine, the var is not returned what am I missing, thanks

```
$('.cap_per_day').blur(function () {
  var sum = 0;
  var remaining = 0;

  $('.cap_per_day').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
      sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
      remaining = total - sum;
    }
  });

  //alert('Total Remaining '+ remaining);
  $(document.getElementById('div.alert-div')).innerHTML = remaining;
  $("div.alert-div").fadeIn(300).delay(2000).fadeOut(400);
});
```

Comment: What var is not returned? Also, a jQuery object doesn't have an `innerHTML` property, and the 'id' selector looks more like a class. Try `$('div.alert-div').html(remaining);`

Comment: Is the var not being returned by the function, or not showing up on the page? The commented alert looks like it should work fine.

Comment: thanks @Rory McCrossan your answer had the correct syntax, now it is working

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what the problem you're trying to solve is, however from your code sample I can tell you that a jQuery object doesn't have an `innerHTML` property, and the 'id' selector looks more like a class. Try this instead:

```
$('div.alert-div').html(remaining);
```